# Unable to create Hive tables in pyspark inside google Colab using hivesupportenabled?

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Here is my code: -

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sparkSession = (SparkSession
                .builder
                .master("local")
                .appName('Colab')
                .config('spark.ui.port', '4050')
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate()
                )

sc.createOrReplaceTempView("my_temp_table");
spark.sql("drop table if exists my_table");
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE Starcraft AS SELECT * FROM my_temp_table")
```

I tried changing

```
master("local")
```

with

also tried adding

```
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")\
```

but to no avail.

The error:-

```
AnalysisException: Hive support is required to CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT);;
'CreateTable `Starcraft`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, ErrorIfExists
+- Project [Name#3094, Dept#3095, Salary#3096]
   +- SubqueryAlias my_temp_table
      +- Relation[Name#3094,Dept#3095,Salary#3096] csv
    master("yarn")
```

Is it a problem of the environment or the code?